# How to fill color inside contours in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to know how to paint inside a contour generated with the python function: `findContours`.
I managed to get the outline of a map and now I want to paint each of the states with a color, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to completely fill inside a closed contour? If so, this link might solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19222620/13069183

Comment: Please post your images separately and your code.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).